# Looking for a bluetooth API documentation for iOS

Tags: ios, api, bluetooth

Google has a [nice documentation on BT](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) but where is the equivalent for apples iOS?
I can import `#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>`but this is not mentioned in the only [documentation I found](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html).

Comment: Apple's documentation is lackluster on Bluetooth. There are a couple of WWDC talks on it though, which might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoreBluetooth framework` is only for Bluetooth Low Energy. 
For Classical Bluetooth, it's `ExternalAccessory framework`.
Bluetooth Low Energy and *classical* bluetooth are really different. You can get more informations here on StackOverFlow looking for the tag *Core-Bluetooth* since it's often repeated or by googling it.
There are a few samples code from Apple. Even if the news change in CoreBluetooth.framework since iOS 6.0 is not well commented (you have to read the header files), the others parts are quite well documented.

By the way, Google has not documented its Bluetooth Low Energy framework since it does not support it officially (Motorola made its own, and there is a project from tierce developers).

Comment: Well in fact I dont need BT LE. I'm programming on a iPad2. But the legacy BT isn't documented well too, or am I missing something?

Comment: What kind of documentation are you actually looking for?

Comment: Im looking for an equilvalent of the Android docu linked in the question. But I guess I found it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008235)

Comment: Indeed, that the documentation of ExternalAccessory, the class you were looking for.